# Can BlueChat Run as A service?

Tags: android, service, bluetooth

Google got Sample Application Called BlueChat which is Something like WhatssAPP application but using Bluetooth for communicate!

As You see if we close the application( END THE APPLICATION ) the connection between two devices will be lost! my question is , is there any way to run this app as a service? i mean the same just like Whatssapp

can we keep the connection between two devices as a service and then each time the device gets the new messages it notifies by notification

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. I would just try it out with the bluetooth chat sample. Create the connection thread from the service.

Comment: Well that's something you can try yourself....